# Sensitivity drops when using SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c++, winapi, setwindowshookex

When I put the hook on the mouse, I periodically lose sensitivity, it increases by ~0.3 seconds (approximately twice). How can I fix this?
My handler code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
if (pMouseStruct != nullptr) {
    switch (wParam) {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        std::cout << "WM_LBUTTONDOWN";
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        std::cout << "WM_LBUTTONUP";
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        std::cout << "WM_RBUTTONDOWN";
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        std::cout << "WM_RBUTTONUP";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);}
```

I put the hook this way:

```
HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, NULL, 0);

MSG message;
while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessage(&message);
}

UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
```

Comment: Two things - (1) _"...if nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the CallNextHookEx function without further processing..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85) and (2) `std::cout << ` might be synchronised.

Comment: In addition to what Richard said, Notice that you using `std::cout`. it is super slow for something like mouse that needs very high response time.

Comment: On a side note: `WH_MOUSE_LL` uses `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`, `WH_MOUSE` uses `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT`. They are not the same thing, so don't get them mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You lose sensitivity in this code, because `std::cout` is very slow. You need a very quick response for this hooking or you obviously lose sensitivity.

If you really need to log in your hook, use something like [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) and log everything asynchronously.

In addition, as Richard mentioned in comments, you need something like this at start of your hook:

```
if (nCode < 0) // do not process message 
    return CallNextHookEx(hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
```

Comment: `OutputDebugString` is just as asynchronous, and doesn't pull in another dependency.

Comment: can I run the code through CreateThread to increase the speed? Will this help?

Comment: @IInspectable Are you sure it is asynchronous? Because I don't see anywhere in msdn.

Comment: @Elberer you cannot use a thread for your hook. problem is logging part. you need to log in a way that is quick and asynchronous. You can write such logging yourself, use API that is like that or use another library for it.

Comment: Once `OutputDebugString` has copied its payload into the shared buffer, code continues to execute. It doesn't wait for a debugger to observe the output. There may not even be a debugger listening. Of course there is some synchronization involved in guarding the shared buffer, though you'd have to be particularly unlucky to ever run into contention over this. [Understanding Win32 "OutputDebugString"](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html) has details on the internals.

Comment: @Elberer Based on what IInspectable said, try using `OutputDebugString` rather than `std::cout` and check if you get better result or not.

Comment: And what if I want to call a function that runs for 10 seconds when a key is pressed?

Comment: @Elberer 10 sec for a mouse click? do that work in a thread. But I think it will be a mess because if you wait for it to finish, you will get a huge lag, and if you don't, what you want to do if multiple clicks come in that 10 seconds?

Comment: That's the problem) As I already asked, via CreateThread (0, 4096, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Action, NULL, 0, NULL) will not work, but how else then? Using RehisterHotKey is not an option, so I chose hooks, but I ran into this problem

Comment: I have no ideas, except CreateThread, how to implement this without loss of sensitivity

Comment: @elb Use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) then. That's asynchronous, an no one is waiting for your response. Though, 10 seconds? What the heck are you doing that takes 10 seconds to complete? That's literally **billions** of CPU instructions.

Comment: I said it for an example. Well, let's say pressing some button starts a cycle

Comment: @elb All low-level mouse hooks installed in a system are executed strictly in sequential order. Any hook you install inevitably adds to the total response time for mouse events. Starting with Windows 7 [the system will silently remove a misbehaving hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)). It is in your interest to keep the code you execute in response to mouse events to an absolute minimum.